# How to set window.location.href

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I have a button on the page which reloads the page based on some value selected. The button's onclick event of calling load_newurl(param).

```
function load_newurl(param) {
    var url = window.location.href;
    var index = url.indexOf("&test=");
    if (index>=0) {  
        url = url.substring(0, index);
    }
    url = url + "&testrun=" + param;
    window.location.href = url;
    window.location.reload();
}
```

Above is my function to reload the page. However, window.location.href never gets changed. Do anyone know why? Am I doing something wrong...?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't call reload.

This should work, provided there's nothing else wrong with your code.

```
function load_newurl(param) {
    var url = window.location.href;
    var index = url.indexOf("&test=");
    if (index>=0) {  
        url = url.substring(0, index);
    }
    url = url + "&testrun=" + param;
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the call to

```
window.location.reload();
```

it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine, but while the `href` is about to be set, the `reload()` refreshes the current page and its `href` stays the same.

Just try your code ommiting `window.location.reload();`.